# Consulta Eloquent usando whereHas

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy realizando una consulta con dos tablas relacionadas. Las tablas son facturas e imágenes, la relación esta correcta y funcionando. Por otro lado estoy realizando una consulta de eloquent utilizando whereHas y también funciona bien.

Estoy realizando un filtro en el cual me debo encontrar las imágenes que no tienen ninguna factura y también debo buscar entre las imágenes que si tienen facturas y filtrar por un campo en especifico de la factura que tiene asociada.

Estoy haciendo esto:

```
$imagenes = Imagen::where('cliente_id', $clienteId)
    ->where('status', '!=', 0)
    ->whereHas('factura', function($query) use ($ncf){
        $query->where('ncf', $ncf)
    ->orWhere('ncf', 'like', $ncf.'%')
    ->orWhere('ncf', 'like', '%'.$ncf);
    })->paginate(10);
```

Funciona, pero solo me filtra las imágenes que tienen una factura asociada, lo que quisiera hacer es que cuando por el formulario se envie el $ncf busque si tiene una factura asociada el valor del ncf y si se manda en blanco entonces que busque entre las imágenes que no tienen facturas.

Comment: Y por qué no dividir la consulta en dos?

Comment: @BetaM ahora que lo pienso tienes mucha razón, he estado tanto tiempo pensando en una solución única que no se me ocurrió.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar una Conditional Clause:

```
$ncf = $request->input('ncf');

$imagenes = Imagen::where('cliente_id', $clienteId)
    ->where('status', '!=', 0)

    ->when($ncf, function ($query) use ($ncf) {
        // cuando $ncf es verdadero, que busque si tiene una factura asociada el valor del ncf
        $query->whereHas('factura', function($q) use ($ncf){
            $q->where('ncf', $ncf)
                ->orWhere('ncf', 'like', $ncf.'%')
                ->orWhere('ncf', 'like', '%'.$ncf);
        });
    }, function ($query) {
        // $ncf es falso (o nulo), que devuelva las que no tienen facturas
        return $query->doesntHave('factura');
    })
    
    ->paginate(10);
```

Referencias:

[Conditional Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses).
[Querying Relationship Absence](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence).

Comment: Exacto muy bien planteado de esa manera la consulta de compone o completa según la condición

Comment: Muchas gracias!